# ASP.NET MVC 2 - "The model of type 'XYZ' could not be updated" when using UpdateModel and LINQ to Entities (.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model set up using LINQ to Entities and have code working that adds to the database as expected. However, I can't get UpdateModel to work when I am using .NET 3.5.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Site.Models.XYZ xyz)
{
    try
    {
        var original = db.XYZ.First(u => u.id == xyz.id);
        UpdateModel(original);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

This results in the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  Message=The model of type 'Site.Models.XYZ' could not be updated.
  Source=System.Web.Mvc
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.UpdateModel[TModel](TModel model, String prefix, String[] includeProperties, String[] excludeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.UpdateModel[TModel](TModel model, String prefix)
       at Site.Controllers.XYZController.Edit(Site.Models.XYZ xyz) in D:***.cs:line 81
  InnerException:
```

If I do `UpdateModel(xyz)` the exception does not occur, but the data does not save either.

How can I get UpdateModel to work with this (without updating to .NET 4.0), why can't it be updated (exception is not helpful as there is no inner exception)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem. Can be done in one of two ways:

```
TryUpdateModel(original)
```

or

```
db.ApplyPropertyChanges(original.EntityKey.EntitySetName, xyz)
```

No idea why `TryUpdateModel` will work but `UpdateModel` won't. Maybe just a bug in .NET 3.5.

Comment: I've just had the same issue and using TryUpdate you can identify which property(s) has not been set to help identify the issue.

Comment: The model binder throws an exception when it fails to update a property on the model. If you are expecting exceptions, as in cases of bad data, then use TryUpdateModel as this one does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

what I do in my MVC projects is grab the source code for the DefaultModelBinder [from Codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) and paste it into a new class in your project, like MyDefaultModelBinder.  then register that model binder in your global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyDefaultModelBinder();
```

this lets you set a breakpoint in the BindModel method, and you can figure out why it's not able to bind.

Comment: That didn't work, a few errors when compiling. "'System.Web.Mvc.DictionaryHelpers' is inaccessible due to its protection level" and "'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider' does not contain a definition for 'TryGetValue' and no extension method 'TryGetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider' could be found"

Comment: yeah, now that you mention it, I think I had to include some other classes, like TypeHelpers and TypeDescriptorHelper.  everything you need should be in the codeplex project, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryUpdateModel()` instead of `UpdateModel()` function to solve this

Both `UpdateModel()` and `TryUpdateModel()` function are used to update the model with the form values and perform validations.

Difference between **`UpdateModel()`** & **`TryUpdateModel()`**

> **`UpdateModel()`** throws an exception if validation fails , where as **`TryUpdateModel()`** will never throw an exception, it return true or false

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this method (this is work for me)

`protected internal void UpdateModel<TModel>(TModel model, string[] includeProperties) where TModel : class;`

Example;

`string[] includeProperty = { xyz.Id.ToString(),xyz.Name};
UpdateModel(uye, includeProperty);`