# MVC3 Edit object containing collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to make Edit form and controller action for the following Model work :

```
public class Form {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public List<FormElement> formElements {get;set;}
}
public class FormElement {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int FormID {get;set;}
    public string Question {get;set;}
    public string Answer {get;set;}
}
```

I've created Edit view for the Form model, used EditorTemplate for FormElement. It looks ok, form elements get rendered properly but when I try to submit the form I get :

```
The model of type 'testApp.Models.Form' could not be updated.
Line 35:         {
Line 36:             var form = db.Forms.Single(f => f.ID== id);
Line 37:             UpdateModel(form, collection); // <- highlighted
```

The Create action worked like a charm done pretty much the same way - I'm able to create new objects with collection of other objects as it's property. So I'm not sure why Edit doesn't work the same way ... any ideas ?

## UPDATE

After several attempts to achieve the goal - having my IEnumerable of FormElement updated I've found this article http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post/Binding-Model-Graphs-with-ASPNETMVC.aspx that is describing what is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
TryUpdateModel(form, collection);
```

EDIT:

Also see [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761085/asp-net-mvc-2-the-model-of-type-xyz-could-not-be-updated-when-using-updatem)

Comment: this almost worked :) It got past the TryUpdateModel line but stopped at db.SaveChanges(); throwing :

`The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.`

What am I missing here - it's just Edit form, no relations have been modified

Comment: Ya, that's odd. I see the Operation Failed for people trying to do  delete operation and they kinda sorta have a resolution but no one else seem to have issues with edit/update operation.

Comment: I tried to make edit view for IEnumerable<testApp.Models.FormElement> using the same editor template but in this case application doesn't throw any exception, though any changes made to the collection are not persisted in database :(

Comment: in the meantime I have verfied that editor template has all the properties implemented and the FormCollection posted to HttpPost Edit method has it correct ( names + values ) so I'm totaly confused